# how to get a url from custom emoji in chat discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to know how I can get the url of a custom emoji in the chat?

When typing the command, followed by an emoji, return the url of the same

Answer (score 3):

Discord rewrite:

```
@client.command()
async def geturl(ctx, emoji: discord.Emoji):
    await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

This gets the emoji object when you type for example !geturl :test_emoji:
The bot will then send a link to the image url of the emoji, in its original dimensions

This only works for custom emojis

Answer (score 2):

Use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the `Emoji` object, which has a [`Emoji.url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji.url) attribute

```
@bot.command()
async def geturl(emoji: discord.Emoji):
    await bot.say(emoji.url)
```

This will throw a `BadArgument` error if you pass it an emoji that doesn't have a url, but the default [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) will prevent it from stopping your bot

Comment: Cool, what if I'm not using commands?

It is taking commands directly from on_message.

I'm not using rewrite. Could I do it, too?

Comment: You can see how the `EmojiConverter` works [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L173).  All of this functionality is available in both branches, async and rewrite, but only documented in the rewrite branch.